# dynamic script for deleting records with F.K constraints for given table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

i need to create script for finding all the tables related with foreign key with the given table and delete the records of the resulted output tables as well as given table with hierarchy dynamically using sql server

This is the stored procedure, i am trying to use for finding all the F.K relationships with hierarchy, but i think its not returning all the foreign key relationships records:

```
create proc dbo.usp_SearchFK 
  @table varchar(256) -- use two part name convention
, @lvl int=0 -- do not change
, @ParentTable varchar(256)='' -- do not change
, @debug bit = 1
as
begin
    set nocount on;
    declare @dbg bit;
    set @dbg=@debug;
    if object_id('tempdb..#tbl', 'U') is null
        create table  #tbl  (id int identity, tablename varchar(256), lvl int, ParentTable varchar(256));
    declare @curS cursor;
    if @lvl = 0
        insert into #tbl (tablename, lvl, ParentTable)
        select @table, @lvl, Null;
    else
        insert into #tbl (tablename, lvl, ParentTable)
        select @table, @lvl,@ParentTable;
    if @dbg=1   
        print replicate('----', @lvl) + 'lvl ' + cast(@lvl as varchar(10)) + ' = ' + @table;

    if not exists (select * from sys.foreign_keys where referenced_object_id = object_id(@table))
        return;
    else
    begin -- else
        set @ParentTable = @table;
        set @curS = cursor for
        select tablename=object_schema_name(parent_object_id)+'.'+object_name(parent_object_id)
        from sys.foreign_keys 
        where referenced_object_id = object_id(@table)
        and parent_object_id <> referenced_object_id; -- add this to prevent self-referencing which can create a indefinitive loop;

        open @curS;
        fetch next from @curS into @table;

        while @@fetch_status = 0
        begin --while
            set @lvl = @lvl+1;
            -- recursive call
            exec dbo.usp_SearchFK @table, @lvl, @ParentTable, @dbg;
            set @lvl = @lvl-1;
            fetch next from @curS into @table;
        end --while
        close @curS;
        deallocate @curS;
    end -- else
    if @lvl = 0
        select * from #tbl;
    return;
end
go
```

And the below script is using the above SP and creating delete statements:

```
insert into #tmp 
exec dbo.usp_SearchFK @table='dbo.M', @debug=0;

declare @where varchar(max) ='where M.id=2' -- if @where clause is null or empty, it will delete tables as a whole with the right order
declare @curFK cursor, @fk_object_id int;
declare @sqlcmd varchar(max)='', @crlf char(2)=char(0x0d)+char(0x0a);
declare @child varchar(256), @parent varchar(256), @lvl int, @id int;
declare @i int;
declare @t table (tablename varchar(128));
declare @curT cursor;
if isnull(@where, '')= ''
begin
    set @curT = cursor for select tablename, lvl from #tmp order by lvl desc
    open @curT;
    fetch next from @curT into @child, @lvl;
    while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin -- loop @curT
        if not exists (select 1 from @t where tablename=@child)
            insert into @t (tablename) values (@child);
        fetch next from @curT into @child, @lvl;
    end -- loop @curT
    close @curT;
    deallocate @curT;

    select  @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + 'delete from ' + tablename + @crlf from @t ;
    print @sqlcmd;
end
else
begin 
    declare curT cursor for
    select  lvl, id
    from #tmp
    order by lvl desc;

    open curT;
    fetch next from curT into  @lvl, @id;
    while @@FETCH_STATUS =0
    begin
        set @i=0;
        if @lvl =0
        begin -- this is the root level
            select @sqlcmd = 'delete from ' + tablename from #tmp where id = @id;
        end -- this is the roolt level

        while @i < @lvl
        begin -- while

            select top 1 @child=TableName, @parent=ParentTable from #tmp where id <= @id-@i and lvl <= @lvl-@i order by lvl desc, id desc;
            set @curFK = cursor for
            select object_id from sys.foreign_keys 
            where parent_object_id = object_id(@child)
            and referenced_object_id = object_id(@parent)

            open @curFK;
            fetch next from @curFk into @fk_object_id
            while @@fetch_status =0
            begin -- @curFK

                if @i=0
                    set @sqlcmd = 'delete from ' + @child + @crlf +
                    'from ' + @child + @crlf + 'inner join ' + @parent  ;
                else
                    set @sqlcmd = @sqlcmd + @crlf + 'inner join ' + @parent ;

                ;with c as 
                (
                    select child = object_schema_name(fc.parent_object_id)+'.' + object_name(fc.parent_object_id), child_col=c.name
                    , parent = object_schema_name(fc.referenced_object_id)+'.' + object_name(fc.referenced_object_id), parent_col=c2.name
                    , rnk = row_number() over (order by (select null))
                    from sys.foreign_key_columns fc
                    inner join sys.columns c
                    on fc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
                    and fc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
                    inner join sys.columns c2
                    on fc.referenced_column_id = c2.column_id
                    and fc.referenced_object_id = c2.object_id
                    where fc.constraint_object_id=@fk_object_id
                )
                    select @sqlcmd =@sqlcmd +  case rnk when 1 then ' on '  else ' and ' end 
                    + @child +'.'+ child_col +'='  +  @parent   +'.' + parent_col
                    from c;
                    fetch next from @curFK into @fk_object_id;
            end --@curFK
            close @curFK;
            deallocate @curFK;
            set @i = @i +1;
        end --while
        print @sqlcmd + @crlf + @where + ';';
        print '';
        fetch next from curT into  @lvl, @id;
    end
    close curT;
    deallocate curT;
end

go
```

Comment: Gosh that's nice. We are not a free code writing service. Maybe you can demonstrate some level of effort.

Comment: `but i think its not returning all the foreign key relationships records` Why do  you think that?

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot easier to setup your foreign key constraints as cascade delete instead of writing this?